# How to toggle between split layout with multiple editors and just one editor using the full screen in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

After working in a multiple column layout it is nice to be able to focus on one file momentarily using the entire application space.  Then, returning to a column view.

In Slick-Edit this is Window / Zoom Toggle.

In VSCode, moving between multiple columns to 1, and then back to multiple loses editor groupings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach for this scenario is using <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to *Open Active File in New Window*. If you close the window the file will still be present in your editor group.

There are some hiccups: I prefer a maximized window over full screen mode, but that will open a new, non-maximized window. In full screen you can prevent that, but will have to use <kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> twice to get back to original view.

Comment: This seems like the best workaround for now. Another workaround is to use multiple profiles but those also include all config and other settings so it will be pretty hard to maintain multiple profiles in sync in long run. See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/95182 for more details.